# Dynamically grab form ID, turn off all buttons in parent form

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I've succeeded in dynamically getting the form ID, but can't seem to turn off the buttons once one of them is clicked. I am trying to use the .prop to turn off the buttons.

As people make choices by clicking on buttons, I want to disable the previous choices.

Code:

```js
function get_parentID(clicked_id) {
  var parent_div = ('#' + clicked_id);
};

function set_path(clicked_id) {
  var divX = ('#' + clicked_id);
  $(divX + '_z').show('slowly');
  //$(divX).prop('disabled', true);
  disable_btn();
}

function disable_btn() {
  $(parent_div + " :input").prop('readonly', true);
};
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.child {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="level_0">Intro Level
  <br></br>
  <form id="level_1_form">
    <input type="button" id="level_1a" value="Choice A" onclick="get_parentID(this.parentNode.id);set_path(this.id);">
    <input type="button" id="level_1b" value="Choice B" onclick="set_path(this.id);get_parentID(this.parentNode.id);">
  </form>

  <br></br>

  <div class="child" id="level_1a_z">This is Level 1 A</br>
    <form id="level_2a_form">
      <input type="button" id="level_2a" value="Choice A-This go nowhere" onclick="get_parentID(this.parentNode.id);set_path(this.id);">
      <input type="button" id="level_1b" value="Choice B-This go nowhere" onclick="set_path(this.id);get_parentID(this.parentNode.id);">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="child" id="level_1b_z">This is Level 1 B
    </br>
    <form id="level_2b_form">
      <input type="button" id="level_2a" value="Choice A-This go nowhere" onclick="get_parentID(this.parentNode.id);set_path(this.id);">
      <input type="button" id="level_2b" value="Choice B-This go nowhere" onclick="set_path(this.id);get_parentID(this.parentNode.id);">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: You need it to keep the syntax you already made? I'd prefer to avoid using onclick.

Comment: I'm open to anyway that works. the goal is to dynamically show hidden divs and to disable previous button choices. The first part works, the second does not. thx

Comment: You're putting the parent ID in a local variable, so it's not in the scope of the other function.

Comment: What is `readonly` supposed to mean for a button? That only makes sense for an input whose value you can change, like text or checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DOM API to select the form elements and iterate through them, attaching a click handler along the way. Then in the click handler you can find all buttons within the form and disable the any that were not clicked. This requires no external libraries.

You need to remove all of the `onclick=""` attributes from your HTML code as this binds the event handler to the form directly.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/vnknunku/))

```
/*    Select the forms and iterate through each form, attaching an event
 *    handler to the click event as you go. You can change the selector 
 *    to be more specific if you have other forms on the page that you 
 *    don't want to be affected
 */ 
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form'), form, i;
for(i = 0; (form = forms[i]); i++) {
    form.onclick = handleClick;
}

/*    This is the function that handles the click event. First we check 
 *    to make sure the clicked element is a button, then get the parent
 *    element and select all buttons contained within. From there we 
 *    iterate through the buttons and check to make sure the button is
 *    not the clicked element, then disable it if not.
 */
function handleClick(e) {
    if(e.target.type === "button") {
        var parent = e.target.parentNode;
        var buttons = parent.querySelectorAll('input'), button, j;

        for(j = 0; (button = buttons[j]); j++) {
            if(e.target.isSameNode(button)) continue;
            button.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you.More complicated than I am capable of at the moment, but happy to learn by studying what you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the parent ID, just use jQuery DOM traversal:

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").find(":input").not(this).prop('readonly', true);
});
```

Comment: So i put this into the function disable_btn() { PLACE BARMAR JQUERY HERE};

Comment: It shouldn't be in the function. This is INSTEAD of using `onclick`, it binds the event handler in code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/o32staad/2/) is what you want, you tell me!

```js
function toggleContent(button) {
    button += '_z';
    $('.parent > div').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == button) {
            $(this).show('slowly');
        }
    });    
}

$(document).on('click', '.parent > form > input', function (e) {
    e = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    toggleContent(e);
});

$('.parent > div').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" id="level_0">Intro Level
    <br></br>
    <form id="level_1_form">
        <input type="button" id="level_1a" value="Choice A" />
        <input type="button" id="level_1b" value="Choice B" />
    </form>
    <br></br>
    <div class="child" id="level_1a_z">This is Level 1 A
        <form id="level_2a_form">
            <input type="button" id="level_1a_1a" value="Choice A-This go nowhere" />
            <input type="button" id="level_1a_1b" value="Choice B-This go nowhere" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="level_1b_z">This is Level 1 B
        <br>
        <form id="level_2b_form">
            <input type="button" id="level_1b_1a" value="Choice A-This go nowhere" />
            <input type="button" id="level_1b_1b" value="Choice B-This go nowhere" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to hide the previous div. I only want to disable the buttons from the previous form once one of the choices has been selected. I plan on adding a back button that will reactivate those buttons if someone want to go back and try a different path.

Comment: Eddited, check it now.